# Bounding error of percentage estimation on binary data for small populations

Tags: binary-data, small-sample, finite-population

Let's say you have a set $X$ with $N$ elements belonging to one of two categories. So, $x \in X$ can be of type A or B (these categories are mutually exclusive). The elements, however, are not classified, nor do we know the proportions in which each category appears on the set. We want to estimate the proportion $P_A$ of elements of $X$ belonging to category $A$.

Classifying the elements is costly. We randomly sample $N_s$ elements of $N$ and determine each element's category. We find there are $A_s$ elements of category A, and use that to estimate the percentage of elements of X that should be of each category:

$P_A \cong \frac{A_s}{N_s} $

1. Is this correct?
2. Is there a way to bound the error of this estimation for different $N$ and $N_s$?
3. Would it change doing this with and without reposition?

It seems like it should be a simple problem but I'm struggling to wrap my head around it.